# How to use C# Enums in Switch Statement while keeping the rest of the code the same

Tags: c#, math, enums, console

I am making a C# maths project where the user answers an addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, power or square root question based on the difficulty level they choose!

I have just started using Enums but I don't know how to put it in my switch statements so the rest of my code works fine.

Here is my code so far:

```
using System;

namespace mathstester
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum UserDifficulty
        {
            Easy,
            Normal,
            Hard
        }

        public enum MathOperation
        {
            Addition = 1,
            Subtraction = 2,
            Multiplication = 3,
            Division = 4,
            Power = 5,
            SquareRoot = 6
        }
        public static (int operationMin, int operationMax) GetMathOperationForDifferentDifficulties(UserDifficulty userDifficulty)
        {

            switch (userDifficulty)
            {
                case UserDifficulty.Easy:
                    return (1, 4);
                case UserDifficulty.Normal:
                    return (1, 5);
                case UserDifficulty.Hard:
                    return (3, 7);
                default:
                    throw new Exception();
            }
        }

        public static (string message, double correctAnswer) GetMathsEquation(MathOperation mathOperation, UserDifficulty userDifficulty)
        {
            int number1;
            int number2;
            Random random = new Random();

            switch (mathOperation)
            {
                case MathOperation.Addition:
                    number1 = random.Next(1000);
                    number2 = random.Next(1000);
                    return ($"{number1} + {number2}", number1 + number2);
                case MathOperation.Subtraction:
                    number1 = random.Next(1000);
                    number2 = random.Next(1000);
                    return ($"{number1} - {number2}", number1 - number2);
                case MathOperation.Multiplication:
                    number1 = userDifficulty == UserDifficulty.Easy ? random.Next(13) : random.Next(1000);
                    number2 = userDifficulty == UserDifficulty.Easy ? random.Next(13) : random.Next(1000);
                    return ($"{number1} * {number2}", number1 * number2);
                case MathOperation.Division:
                    number1 = random.Next(10000);
                    number2 = random.Next(1000);
                    return ($"{number1} / {number2}", number1 / (double)number2);
                case MathOperation.Power:
                    number1 = random.Next(13);
                    number2 = random.Next(5);
                    return ($"{number1} ^ {number2}", Math.Pow(number1, number2));
                case MathOperation.SquareRoot:
                    number1 = random.Next(1000);
                    return ($"√{number1}", Math.Sqrt(number1));
                default:
                    throw new Exception();
            }
        }

        public static int GetResult(int numberOfQuestionsLeft, string userDifficulty)
        {
            int score = 0;
            Random random = new Random();
            var (operationMin, operationMax) = GetMathOperationForDifferentDifficulties(userDifficulty);
            while (numberOfQuestionsLeft > 0)
            {
                int mathOperation = random.Next(operationMin, operationMax);
                var (message, correctAnswer) = GetMathsEquation(mathOperation, userDifficulty);
                if (mathOperation == 4 || mathOperation == 6)
                {
                    Console.Write($"To the nearest integer, What is {message} =");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write($"What is {message} =");
                }
                double userAnswer = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                if (Math.Round(correctAnswer) == userAnswer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                    score++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
                }
                numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
            }

            return score;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userDifficulty = "";
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What difficulty level would you like to do! Please type E for Easy, N for Normal and H for hard");
                userDifficulty = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            } while (userDifficulty != "E" && userDifficulty != "N" && userDifficulty != "H");

            int numberOfQuestions = 0;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many questions would you like to answer? Please type a number divisible by 10!");
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfQuestions);
            } while (numberOfQuestions % 10 != 0);

            int score = GetResult(numberOfQuestions, userDifficulty);
            Console.WriteLine($"You got a score of {score} out of {numberOfQuestions}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: don't keep using  `new Random()` Keep a single, static instance of it in your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to lie in the selection of difficulties - in your `Main()` method, you take an input of `E`, `N`, or `H` for difficulty, which is then passed to `GetResult()` and onwards to `GetMathOperationForDifferentDifficulties()`

However, as Enums are underpinned by a numeric type in C#, this will fail and throw an exception.

To fix it, you need to convert the `E`, `N`, or `H` to `UserDifficulty.Easy`, `UserDifficulty.Normal`, or `UserDifficulty.Hard` respectively, and then pass them over that way.

Here's how you could modify `Main()` to do this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string difficultyInput = "";
    UserDifficulty userDifficulty = UserDifficulty.Easy // default to start
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What difficulty level would you like to do! Please type E for Easy, N for Normal and H for hard");
        difficultyInput = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    } while (difficultyInput != "E" && difficultyInput != "N" && difficultyInput != "H");

    switch(difficultyInput) {
        case "E": 
            userDifficulty = UserDifficulty.Easy; 
            break;
        case "N": 
            userDifficulty = UserDifficulty.Normal; 
            break;
        case "H": 
            userDifficulty = UserDifficulty.Hard; 
            break;
    }

    int numberOfQuestions = 0;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many questions would you like to answer? Please type a number divisible by 10!");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfQuestions);
    } while (numberOfQuestions % 10 != 0);

    int score = GetResult(numberOfQuestions, userDifficulty);
    Console.WriteLine($"You got a score of {score} out of {numberOfQuestions}");
}
```

Bear in mind you'd need to alter `GetResult()` to take a `UserDifficulty` input instead of a `string`, too

Comment: Thank You!! But on the second line where you wrote `UserDifficulty userDifficulty = UserDifficulty.Easy` is there a way to set `userDifficulty` to `UserDifficulty.Empty` or something like that? It would help make the code look cleaner!

Comment: If you were to add that to your enum, then yes.